# Binding lost when changing DataContext

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, viewmodel, datacontext

I have a combobox in my MainWindow window.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupMethods}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroupMethod}"/>
```

I bind it to List which is in my base ViewModel class and it works at beginning.
I want that combobox to be everywhere in my application. 
Now i switch DataContext of MainWindow to another viewModel which inherits from ViewModelBase (where the GroupMethods property is), i update that property in some point and see no results. Binding simply didn't recognise that DataContext has changed and still "looks" at previously saved property. 
Fireing PropertyChanged event didn't solve the problem.
How do I make it work?

Comment: In general you should not be switching the DataContext midway through your application.  I'm confused what property you are updating?  Is it the one on the original ViewModel or the new DataContext?

Comment: Should work, you're going to have to show more code from your viewmodel and where are switching the datacontext maybe

Comment: I have something like that: ViewModelBase and ViewModel1, ViewModel2 which both inherits from base.
ViewModelBase has a property GroupMethods which my combobox has binding to.
Now, when I set MainWindow.DataContext to ViewModel1 - it works, then i set MainWindow.DataContext to viewmodel2 - binding won't work even when I fire propertyChanged event

Comment: OK I apolagise for all mess. after a hour of testing I've remembered that i have a ContentControl inside my Windwow ;)
Thanks for all Your time, good bye